# Cleanup Vertex Weights

Tags: mesh, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

Is there any way to cleanup/remove empty vertex weights?  Namely, on each vertex in a mesh, remove any vertex weights that have a value of zero or something close to it.

Note that I am referring to something more distinct than vertex groups.  When you have a vertex selected, a "Vertex Weights" tab will appear in the Properties Panel, and it will list all of the vertex weights affecting a particular vertex.

[image]

Stuff like that in the image.  I'd like something to remove all of the vertex weights that are at 0 from each vertex.  Or any that have a weight of less than 0.001, since the display there only seems to go out to 3 digits past the decimal point.

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23432/how-to-batch-remove-zero-weight-vertices-from-vgroup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to be in Weight Paint Mode.  From there, goto Weights >> Clean.  The settings for which threshold you want (if its other than zero) can be found on the tool shelf, on the Clean Vertex group Properties.

Comment: In Blender 2.8X, the "Clean" option in Weight Paint Mode has a slight small issue if set to 0.00 value. While the note tip appearing state that it will remove any weight group (on selected verticles) with a value lower or equals to the number, there's an internal error margin (float precision) for the 0.00 value which return a value below zero (like -0.0000134), hence doesn't remove the 0 weight groups. Setting it to a super low value like 0.001 is a work around.