# Selecting all faces visible by camera

Tags: scripting, selection-tools, visibility

I need to select all faces that are visible from a certain camera, optimally via script because I have to do it very often.
And actually, I already wrote a script that is doing this... in theory. But I found the same issue that has been already described in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/69392/select-all-visible-faces-possible-script-needed): why is the selection depending (1) on the distance between object and camera and (2) size of the faces?

I am using Blender 2.82 and tried all the combinations of X-Ray and Wireframe view and X-Ray Alpha, but I didn't found any to solve the issue. I heard there was, until Blender 2.79, a thing like "Limited selection to visible" that disappeared in newer versions and has been integrated in X-Ray. But I guess that this would not solve the problem...

Can anyone give me a hint how to handle this properly?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45146/how-to-find-all-objects-in-the-cameras-view-with-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all objects in the Camera's view with Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45146/how-to-find-all-objects-in-the-cameras-view-with-python)

Comment: Actually not because as far as I understand, the linked answer selects all objects visible from camera. In my case, I only want to select all the faces of an object that are visible from camera point of view.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40826/15543 (re 2.79 and using space.use_occlude_geometry)

Comment: Quick look and could use `space.shading.show_xray_wireframe=False`  instead.

Comment: I don't get the `space` correctly... isn't it the `v3d` in `for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            v3d = area.spaces[0]`?