# how to check if a vertex group is empty or not with python

Tags: python, modeling, mesh, scripting, vertex-groups

I am figuring out a way to check if vertex group is empty or not. if it contains at least 1 vertex or totally empty.

I am trying to make if condition to check for empty vertex group and delete the vertex group if it's empty

can I do this with vertex group data or should i use functions from bmesh

Comment: it looks like there is a script here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16517/how-to-quickly-remove-all-zero-weight-vertex-groups

Answer (score 2):

**Using list comprehension**

similar to that  [used in this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/75240/15543)

Because we are only interested in empty group will use python `any` to move on quickly when a non empty group is found.

```
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
for vg in ob.vertex_groups:
    mtvg = not any(vg.index in [g.group for g in v.groups] for v in me.vertices)
    print(vg.name, mtvg)
```

Then if vertex group `vg` is empty can remove with

```
ob.vertex_groups.remove(vg)
```